# PID Gains: Drop in control loop rate, need to retune?

Tags: quadcopter, mobile-robot, control, pid, stability

Good Day,

I am working on an autonomous quadcopter. May I ask if there is a significant difference if my control loop dropped from 500Hz to 460Hz due to added lines of code that would require retuning of the PID gains? And if retuning is required, is it correct to assume that only the I and D gains should be retweaked since they are the only constants which are time dependent? Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three constants should be able to stay the same assuming that you calculate the derivative and integral using the actual time step size.

The only effect of a lower sampling rate should be a bigger "delay" in the plant, you are trying to control, due to zero order hold. Also the plant should not have any important dynamics above half the sampling frequency (Nyquist frequency).